# df.to_sql with if_exists="append" fails with TypeError: Invalid Argument sent to create_engine

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm currently using 0.24.2 of Pandas, 11.2 of Postgresql, and 1.3.2 of sqlalchemy trying to write my dataframe to a postgresql database using `if_exists="append"`.  When the code runs the following error is returned:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'if_exists' sent to create_engine(), using
configuration PGDialect_psycopg2/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the
keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.
```

The code is straight forward and looks exactly like the example from the documentation:

```
def write_to_db(df):
   engine = create_engine(
         "postgresql://esammons@localhost:5432/testdb", if_exists='append'
        )
   df.to_sql("ctcl", engine)
```

The code works when executed without the `if_exists` option.

Comment: Isn't `if_exists` a parameter of `to_sql` and not `create_engine`.  Should that be `df.to_sql("ctcl", engine, if_exists='append')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def write_to_db(df):
   engine = create_engine(
         "postgresql://esammons@localhost:5432/testdb"
        )
   df.to_sql("ctcl", engine, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: Nice answer! @Ahh_real_numbers

Comment: Sorry this was totally my fault, I typoed the line of code.  I had not added the parameter initially and when I went back I placed it on the wrong line.  Chalk this one up to brain dead user.  Thank you!